# \n doesn't work in Python 3.6

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

It might be very basic thing, and i don't see what I'm i doing wrong.

I do have a dictionary:

```
elSPH = {
'%SiO2': 52.79,
'%MgO': 0.10,
'%Na2O': 4.33,
'%Al2O3': 29.50
}
```

And i want to make a new string line for each element to look like this:

```
%SiO2: 52.79
%MgO: 0.10
%Na2O: 4.33
%Al2O3: 29.50
```

So I've tried

```
''.join('{}{}\n'.format(key, val) for key, val in elSPH.items())
```

And got output:

```
'%SiO252.79\n%MgO0.1\n%Na2O4.33\n%Al2O329.5\n'
```

Is there a way how i could make this \n new line break working? 
For some reason it's even not working on a simple things like:

```
In: d = 'Hello\nworld'
In: d 
Out: 'Hello\nworld'
```

Comment: Newline works with print.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. This question isn't really about dictionaries, or using `join`, or even [tag:jupyter-notebook].

Comment: it was a good question and yet people mass downvote, unfortunately

Answer (score 6):

I think you'll find that it is working, you just need to actually `print` the string to see the new-line:

```
>>> print('%SiO252.79\n%MgO0.1\n%Na2O4.33\n%Al2O329.5\n')
%SiO252.79
%MgO0.1
%Na2O4.33
%Al2O329.5
```

Comment: Thanks. So calling print - is the only way how i could make \n work? I'm asking, because i want to add this result to QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit (in PyQt5) later

Comment: The documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html) seems to suggest that newlines should work as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

Print the output:

```
In: d = 'Hello\nworld'
In: print(d) 
Hello
world
```

The new line is there, but it will only render as a separate line if you print it.

Comment: Thanks. So calling print - is the only way how i could make \n work? I'm asking, because i want to add this result to QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit (in PyQt5) later

Comment: It should work with that

Comment: Nope, not working for me -- python 3.9.12 AMD64 on win32 'Hello\nworld'